# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint LARAVEL 7

Tags: laravel-7, migration

Quiero anexar una columna a la tabla de usuarios y que la columna sea la llave foranea para la tabla de alumnos, pero cuando realizo el migrate:fresh me sale error 1215. Mi código es el siguiente.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->foreignId('alumno_id')->nullable()->references('id')->on('alumnos');

            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Y la tabla de alumnos es la siguiente
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('alumnos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('nombre');
            $table->string('ap_paterno');
            $table->string('ap_materno');
            $table->string('matricula')->unique();
            $table->string('correo');
            $table->string('carrera');
            $table->string('ingreso');
            $table->string('habilidades');
            $table->string('seguro')->nullable();
            $table->string('curriculum')->nullable();

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Me encuentro trabajando en laravel 7

Comment: Y tus migraciones ¿en qué orden se ejecutan?, es decir ¿cuál tabla se esta creando primero y cuál después?

Comment: Primero se ejecuta la de users y luego la de alumnos.

Comment: No puedes referenciar una llave foránea a una tabla que no existe. Para solucionarlo puedes cambiar el orden de las migraciones, o actualizar la tabla users agregando la fk una vez que hayas creado la tabla alumnos.

Comment: @SheilaUcChan pues de ahi el error, no puedes crear una tabla que requiere como llave foránea un valor de una tabla que aún no existe

Comment: Es verdad, no habia tomado eso en cuenta. Muchas gracias